# Issue on jQuery and Click Function

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to create a drop down menu list using jQuery and simple CSS at this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/TApaE/) the sliding works fine but I don't know why on click function the page also refreshes (this is more obvious when you look at the [image]
  Here is the code I have:

```
<style>
.musthidden{display:none;}
</style>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li id="two"><a href="#">Two</a>
                  <ul class="musthidden">
                    <li><a href="#">Two _ 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Two _ 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Two _ 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Two _ 4</a></li>
                  </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
 $("#two").on("click",function(){
    $(".musthidden").slideToggle();
 });
</script>
```

Can you please let me know why this is happening?

Comment: I'm not seeing any reloading in your fiddle.

Comment: Me neither - Windows8 IE11

Comment: I'm seeing it in Chrome. Watch the favicon in the corner when you click the `#two` `li`. It's reloading because of the inner `<a>` (anchor) tag. The reason, you're not seeing it is because it's in an `<iframe />`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

click function should be:

```
$("#two").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".musthidden").slideToggle();
 });
```

`e.preventDefault()` says: do not carry out any other functions binded to this event, stop after hitting this function. So it shouldn't do anything after.

`e` is event object that gets sent through the `click` event, most other events also have `e`

see updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TApaE/1/) without any refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You should use prevent.default() function. Like this:

```
 $("#two").on("click",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".musthidden").slideToggle();
});
```